# How to check onSuccess in API flow in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I was implementing a POST api flow and sending data on click of button.
below is the code I handled, but not sure Snackbar is not getting displayed and data is getting stored successfully, maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            String groupNameVal = groupNameController.text;
                            String emailVal = emailController.text;
                            String zipCodeVal = zipCodeController.text;
                            String buildNumberVal = buildNumberController.text;
                            String platformVal = platformController.text;

                            Future<http.Response> createGroupAPI(
                                String groupName,
                                String email,
                                String zipCode,
                                String buildNumber,
                                String platform) async {
                              final response = await http.post(
                                Uri.parse(
                                    'https://cpoc-consmobile-api-dev.kubeodc-test.corp.intranet/user'),
                                headers: <String, String>{
                                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                },
                                body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                                  'name': groupNameVal,
                                  'email': emailVal,
                                  'zipcode': zipCodeVal,
                                  'buildName': buildNumberVal,
                                  'platform': platformVal
                                }),
                              );

                              if (response.statusCode == 201) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('User Group has been created!'),
                                  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                                ));
                              } else {
                                throw Exception('Failed to create group.');
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Color(0xff0962ff),
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            Strings.create_group,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Also if I checked if it fails or throws exception then its going into else part and printing the logs.

Comment: Can you confirm if the `response.statusCode` is exactly 201 and not something else from the 200 range?

Comment: @RohanThacker So, this is postman call. I checked and it was 200 so i updated and ran the code again. Still it didnt work for me, its not showing snackbar

Comment: Can you debug and check if the code is code within the if condition is actually being executed?

Comment: yes correct, else part is triggering but not if (success) part

Comment: In your widget tree, is a the Scaffold Widget used?

Comment: @RohanThacker yes

Answer (score 0):

You should use exception handling that is try-catch.
You should write your success code in try block and throw exception in catch block.
Note: if you don't want that compiler should not throw exception then use print or log method instead of
`thow Exception('Error') ;`